# Topology of a balaclava

Tags: geometric-topology

Consider a balaclava that fits over the head and has 3 distinct holes; one for each eye and one for the mouth.

My question is: how many holes does this have, from a topological perspective? I can see two possibilities:

Ignoring the eye & mouth holes, the item is basically a rubber sheet that has deformed to fit over the head. In this case, I would say it has no other holes, so the answer to my question would be three.

Alternatively, it could be considered as a hollow sphere with 4 holes; the neck hole being the additional one.

Which interpretation, if any, is correct?

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of [manifolds with boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary).

Comment: A sphere with a hole in it is (in certain conditions) homeomorphic to the plane. The reason a regular sphere isn't​ homeomorphic to a plane is a single pesky point that you can take to be anywhere on the sphere. Cutting a hole in the sphere removes that point

Answer (score 0):

The first interpretation is correct. There are essentially three independent loops that can't shrink to points.

Think about a hollow sphere with just one hole. There are no loops that don't shrink. The surface is topologically the same as a disk.

Comment: Thankyou. It does seem counterintuitive that making a 'hole' in something results in a shape that is homeomorphic to something that does not have a 'hole'.

Comment: Possibly I'm confusing handles with holes?

Comment: There are possible "holes" in every dimension. The hollow sphere has a single $2$-dimensional  hole and no $1$-dimensional holes. Puncturing the sphere destroys the $2$-dimensional hole without introducing a $1$-dimensional hole, so no holes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)